# App created with Phonegap Dreamweaver doesn't work on Tablets

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, tablet

I created an app with Dreamweaver and Phonegap, and it works perfect on mobiles. But it doesn't work on tablets!

I tried it first with my tablet, an Smartq t10, and i though it was because it had Android 2.2

However, when i published my app one user told me it didn't work on its tablet with Android 4.0, so the reason is not the android version.

I have 2 questions.

1. Could I block the search on Google Play so the app just appear to mobile phones?
2. Is there anyway to fix this problem for tablets?

I wouldn't like getting bad reviews because the app doesn't work on tablets.

Greetings.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is too vague. Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: The main screen appears, but then, when the user touch a button to go to the next page, it just doesn't work. That's what the user with a 4.0 tablet told me. 

In my case, with android 2.2 tablet, the buttons were invisible, you couldn't see the text inside them. I don't understand why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot tell what is wrong with your code, I can help you to filter out the tablet on google play.

manifest:

```
android:minSdkVersion="xx" (>=4)

<compatible-screens>
    <!--  as of API 19, some named const are not supported in compatible-screens node
    https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34076
    xxhdpi = 480
    tvdpi = 213

    nexus 7 : tvdpi
     -->

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="213" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="213" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all xlarge size screens  >= 7" -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="213" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />
</compatible-screens>
```

remove the combination you don't want. (eg: all xlarge)

Thoses devices will show up in google play console as "not compatible".

Also, you can refine this with the "excluded device" from google play console.

Use a reference web page like http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=pdachooser (OS:android, Diagoinal >=8'') to help you identifying the terminales.